# Invalid URL (POST /v1/completions/) when using the openai api on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, openai-api

I am creating an app whereby i utilise the openai api to craft an itinerary based on user inputs. The issue I am facing is that when i run the app on expo and click the button to generate, I keep getting the following error in my log :

ERROR  404
ERROR  Invalid URL (POST /v1/completions/)
ERROR  null
ERROR  invalid_request_error

I am unsure as to what causes the 404 because the openai component does the fetching. Thank you in advance !

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import OpenAI from 'openai';

const Home = () => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState('');

    const openai = new OpenAI({
        apiKey: 'my api key goes here'
    });

    const promptGen = (numOfPeople, location, startDate, endDate, address, tripType, dietaryReq, isDisabled, activities, budget) => {// returns a crafted prompt based on the inputs}

    const generate = async () => {

        try {
            const generatedPrompt = promptGen('3','Bali','10 September 2023', '15 september 2023', 'Sp, Jl. Camplung Tanduk Jl. Dhyana Pura No.103, Seminyak, Kuta, Badung Regency, Bali 80361, Indonesia', 'Single trip', 'Halal', false, 'Hiking, beach, nightclubs', '500'); // I pass this as the prompt

            console.log(generatedPrompt); 

            const res = await openai.completions.create({
                model: "text-davinci-003",
                prompt: generatedPrompt,
                max_tokens: 3000
            });
            console.log(res);
            setResult(res.choices[0].text);
        } catch (error) {
            if (error instanceof OpenAI.APIError) {
                console.error(error.status);  // e.g. 401
                console.error(error.message); // e.g. The authentication token you passed was invalid...
                console.error(error.code);  // e.g. 'invalid_api_key'
                console.error(error.type);  // e.g. 'invalid_request_error'
              } else {
                // Non-API error
                console.log(error);
              }
        }
    }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>itinerary Gen</Text>
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={generate}>
            <Text>Generate itinerary</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{result}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Home

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

I tried to maybe add a base url but nonetheless I get the same issue. I did use openai api for a react project and it seemed to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

OpenAI API not support to call from React Native to protect your API key, you can call API in your server. Hope it help [Info here](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/issues/199#issuecomment-1642859127)